# Filling in HTML inputs with VBA. result has inputs filled in but treats it like its empty

Tags: html, vba

Bit of an odd problem I have encountered. I am filling in a website for my work (cannot share) in order to speed up some searches for accounts. I have managed to fill in what I need but it still treats it as if the boxes are empty even though they are now filled with the data I selected.

One workaround I am currently using is tabbing through everything, for some reason that works but I really do not want to resort to using sendkeys.

I have tried changing the aEle.innerText to value and placeholder but not have worked.

Here is the code I am using, it's pretty messy right now, the html I am using does not use any IDs so i had to loop through each tag. any input would be appreciated. Thanks

```
Dim fullAcct, acct, branch, daterange1, daterange2 As String
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement
Dim y, branchInput, accountInput, dateInput As Integer 'integer variables used as counters

'split selected account# into strings
fullAcct = selection
branch = Left(fullAcct, 3)
acct = Mid(fullAcct, 5, 6)
daterange1 = Date
daterange2 = DateAdd("yyyy", -25, daterange1) 'max date range

Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
objIE.Visible = True
'navigate IE to this web page
objIE.Navigate "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com"

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

'set the counter for the for each loop and indicators of what to update
y = 1
branchInput = 2 'brach input
accountInput = 3
dateInput = 5
'for each <a> element in the collection of objects with a tag name "input"
For Each aEle In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

    '**tried using .value and .placerholder but innerText seemed to work the best
    If y = branchInput Then 'check for second input (branch)
        aEle.innerText = branch
     End If
    If y = accountInput Then 'check for third input (account#)
        aEle.innerText = acct
    End If
    If y = dateInput Then 'check for date input
        aEle.innerText = daterange2
    End If
   y = y + 1
Next

SendKeys "{TAB 10}" 'must be tabbed through for some reason or the data isnt read

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

End Sub
```

Comment: there was another posting a few months back. there was a mention that some websites require an actual keypress in the input field ... that may be the reason that TAB makes it work.  i will try to find the posting.

Comment: note: use `elseif ...` instead of `end if` `if ...`   ...... looks neater

Comment: try `aEle.focus` `aEle.value = branch`

Comment: You neither post here a link to that webpage nor the portion of html elements you are hurdling with. That means, you are expecting us to provide you with a solution by making a good guess, ain't it? However, try to search out how `keyboard events` work in vba which in my guess will take care of your issue. Thanks.